# How to ensure a signal handler never yields to a thread within the same process group?

Tags: linux, multithreading, signals, glibc, nptl

This is a bit of a meta question since I think I have a solution that works for me, but it has its own downsides and upsides. I need to do a fairly common thing, catch `SIGSEGV` on a thread (no dedicated crash handling thread), dump some debug information and exit.

The catch here is the fact that upon crash, my application runs `llvm-symbolizer` which takes a while (relatively speaking) and causes a yield (either because of `clone + execve` or exceeding the time quanta for the thread, I've seen latter happen when doing symbolication myself in-process using `libLLVM`). The reason for doing all this is to get a stack trace with demangled symbols and with line/file information (stored in a separate DWP file). For obvious reasons I do not want a yield happening across my `SIGSEGV` handler since I intend to terminate the application (thread group) after it has executed and never return from the signal handler.

I'm not that familiar with Linux signal handling and with glibc's wrappers doing magic around them, though, I know the basic gotchas but there isn't much information on the specifics of handling signals like whether synchronous signal handlers get any kind of special priority in terms of scheduling.

Brainstorming, I had a few ideas and downsides to them:

- `pthread_kill(<every other thread>, SIGSTOP)` - Cumbersome with more threads, interacts with signal handlers which seems like it could have unintended side effects. Also requires intercepting thread creation from other libraries to keep track of the thread list and an increasing chance of pre-emption with every system call. Possibly even change their contexts once they're stopped  to point to a syscall `exit` stub or flat out use `SIGKILL`.
- Global flag to serve as cancellation points for all thread (kinda like `pthread_cancel/pthread_testcancel`). Safer but requires a lot of maintenance and across a large codebase it can be hellish, in addition to a a mild performance overhead. Global flag could also cause the error to cascade since the program is already in an unpredictable state so letting any other thread run there is already not great.
- "Abusing" the scheduler which is my current pick, with my implementation as one of the answers. Switching to `FIFO` scheduling policy and raising priority therefore becoming the only runnable thread in that group.
- Core dumps  not an option since the goal here was to avoid them in the first place. I would prefer not requiring a helper program aside from from the symbolizer as well.

Environment is a typical `glibc` based Linux (4.4) distribution with `NPTL`.

I know that crash handlers are fairly common now so I believe none of the ways I picked are that great, especially considering I've never seen the scheduler "hack" ever get used that way. So with that, does anyone have a better alternative that is cleaner and less riskier than the scheduler "hack" and am I missing any important points in my general ideas about signals?

**Edit:** It seems that I haven't really considered MP in this equation (as per comments) and the fact that other threads are still runnable in an MP situation and can happily continue running alongside the `FIFO` thread  on a different processor. I can however change the affinity of the process to only execute on the same core as the crashing thread, which basically will effectively freeze all other threads at schedule boundaries. However, that still leaves the "FIFO thread yielding due to blocking IO" scenario open.

It seems like the `FIFO + SIGSTOP` option is the best one, though I do wonder if there are any other tricks that can make a thread unschedulable short of using `SIGSTOP`. From the docuemntation it seems like it's not possible to set a thread's CPU affinity to zero (leaving it in a limbo state where it's technically runnable except no processors are available for it to run on).

Comment: Stopping a multithreaded process is inherently "fuzzy". On a multiprocessor system, other threads may be running in parallel when the signal arrives at your `SIGSEGV` thread. And even on a single-threaded system with signaled thread running at real-time priority, other threads might run while your clone/exec is happening (if waiting for memory to be swapped during `clone`, or waiting for code to be read from disk during `exec`). I think `pthread_kill`/`SIGSTOP` has the best potential -- perhaps along with RT priority. Once other threads are stopped, you can do whatever's needed.

Comment: I'd at least consider getting the stack trace by an out-of-band mechanism. One way is to use systemtap, having it wait for a SIGSEGV to be raised by your process. The other is to run your process as a child of another process who just waits for it to stop, then uses libunwind to get a stack trace. The SIGSEGV signal handler would send SIGSTOP to the entire process, which will stop every thread ASAP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the best solution I could come up (parts omitted for brevity but it shows the principle) with, my basic assumption being that in this situation the process runs as root. This approach can lead to resource starvation in case things go really bad and requires privileges (if I understand the `man(7) sched` page correctly) I run the part of the signal handler that causes preemptions under the `OSSplHigh` guard and exit the scope as soon as I can. This is not strictly C++ related since the same could be done in C or any other native language.

```
void spl_get(spl_t& O)
{
    os_assert(syscall(__NR_sched_getattr,
        0, &O, sizeof(spl_t), 0) == 0);
}

void spl_set(spl_t& N)
{
    os_assert(syscall(__NR_sched_setattr,
        0, &N, 0) == 0);
}

void splx(uint32_t PRI, spl_t& O) {
    spl_t PL = {0};

    PL.size = sizeof(PL);
    PL.sched_policy = SCHED_FIFO;
    PL.sched_priority = PRI;

    spl_set(PL, O);
}

class OSSplHigh {
    os::spl_t OldPrioLevel;

public:
    OSSplHigh() {
        os::splx(2, OldPrioLevel);
    }

    ~OSSplHigh() {
        os::spl_set(OldPrioLevel);
    }
};
```

The handler itself is quite trivial using `sigaltstack` and `sigaction` though I do not block `SIGSEGV` on any thread. Also oddly enough [syscalls sched_setattr and sched_getattr](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sched_setattr.2.html) or the struct definition weren't exposed through glibc contrary to the documentation.

---

**Late Edit:** The best solution involved sending `SIGSTOP` to all threads (by intercepting `pthread_create` via linker's `--wrap` option) to keep a ledger of all running threads, thank you to suggestion in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

> upon crash, my application runs llvm-symbolizer

That is likely to cause deadlocks. I can't find any statement about llvm-symbolizer being async-signal safe. It's likely to call `malloc`, and if so will surely deadlock if the crash also happens inside `malloc` (e.g. due to heap corruption elsewhere).

> Switching to FIFO scheduling policy and raising priority therefore becoming the only runnable thread in that group.

I believe you are mistaken: a `SCHED_FIFO` thread will run *so long as it is runnable* (i.e. does not issue any blocking system calls). If the thread does issue such a call (which it has to: to e.g. `open` the separate `.dwp` file), it will block and other threads will become runnable.

TL;DR: there is no easy way to achieve what you want, and it seems unnecessary anyway: what do you care that other threads continue running while the crashing thread finishes its business?

Comment: It's a separate program executed by the signal handler, the addresses of the backtrace are passed down to it, its job is to do the heavy lifting of handling dwarf debug data (ie. line tables), demangling symbols, de-basing everything etc. It constructs a flat buffer that contains the output passing it back to the crash handler. Running `llvm-symbolizer` is intended, it's a fairly advanced stack trace dumper.

Comment: And the reason I don't want other threads to keep running is because `SIGSEGV` means the program may be or is in an unpredictable state, it makes sense to minimize the possible damage (ie. file corruption) by stopping all threads at their next possible schedule point. It is possible to semi-gracefully handle a crash, the main goal being minimizing the chance of the crash causing a potential data corruption.